# how to show a scalar product defined by trace of matrices is non-degenerate

Tags: linear-algebra

> a) Let $V$ be a vector space of all $n \times n$ matrices over $\Bbb R $ , define the scalar product of two matrices $A$ and $B$ by 
>   $$\langle A,B\rangle = \text{tr}(AB)$$ 
>   where tr is trace. Show that this is a scalar product and non-degenerate.
>
> b) If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, show that $\text{tr}(AA) \ge 0$ and $\text{tr}(AA) > 0$ if $A \neq 0$. Thus defines a positive definite scalar product on the space of symmetric matrices.

$a)$ I don't have problem showing that it is scalar product. I don't know how to show that it is non degenerate. I know $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ji}b_{ij} = 0 , \forall b_{ij} \in \Bbb R$. Is it enough to show $A = 0$?

$b)$ I am not sure if this is correct $\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ji}a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ji}^2 \ge 0 $. Is this correct?

Comment: You are missing a transpose in (a), it should be something like $tr(A^{t}B)$. $tr(AB)$ itself is degenerate. eg. $tr(A^2) = 0$ for any nilpotent matrix $A$ of degree 2. Your (b) is correct.

Comment: @achillehui the problem is from Serge Lang Linear Algebra chapter 6. Page no 112, you can find it [here](http://gonzaloandres.ublog.cl/archivos/13543/linear_algebra.pdf)

Comment: You are missing a 'not' in your title.

Comment: oh .. sorry .. i'll fix it.

Comment: @achillehui, the trace would be degenerate if there were a matrix $A \ne 0$ such that $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = 0$ *for all matrices* $B$.

Comment: @andreascaranti Oops, my mistake. I've been confused that with the non-degeneracy as an inner product. In any event, $tr(A^{t}B)$ is an inner product and $tr(A^{t}A) > 0$ for $A \ne 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part (a), suppose the matrix $A$ satisfies $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = 0$ for all matrices $B$. Choose $B = e_{ij}$ for all $i, j$, where $e_{ij}$ is the matrix with 1 in the $i,j$ position, and 0 elsewhere.

I think part (b) is correct.

Comment: Part (b) is indeed correct, due to the fact that $A$ is assumed symmetric.

Comment: I think part a) of the question is right because one of matrices must be all zero. If only the diagonal is zero as you propose the matrix product is not zero even the trace is different from 0, right?

Comment: @kneidell How is part b) right if $a_{i,j}\neq a_{j,i}$?

Comment: Hi @PedroGomes. It usually isn't. Consider for example the case where $A$ is nilpotent of order $2$. In general one takes the form $(A,B)\mapsto Tr(A^T B)$, for which it holds that $Tr(A^TA)$ is simply the $2$-norm of $A$, i.e. the euclidean norm of an element of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Comment: @kneidell But the multiplication you are using inside the trace is the normal matrix multiplication, right? n

Comment: @kneidell    Why are you adding the transpose, the book does not use it?

Comment: @PedroGomes Yes, it is regular matrix multiplication. The question the OP posted was about $A$ symmetric, so the transpose is unnecessary. I was just commenting that in a more general setting it is possible to get a positive definite form on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, if one wishes to do so.

Comment: @kneidell            Consider the matrix is not symmetric? How is part b) correct? Because I am self-studying the same book and there is no symmetry assumption. My question was marked as duplicate of this one but apparently there is a difference.Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @PedroGomes Please read my comments.. I just said that part (b) is incorrect if $A$ is not assumed symmetric...